# need help in developers.android.com tutorial

Tags: android

Hi I was studying `backstack` and `launchmode` from
Android developers.

but not able to understand the meaning of note .
Please explain asap

cant attach image

Note: When a new instance of an `Activity` is created, the user can press the Back `Button` to return to the previous `Activity`. But when an existing instance of an `Activity` handles a new Intent, the user cannot press the Back Button to return to the state of the `Activity` before the new `Intent` arrived in `onNewIntent()`

under single top

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an activity labeled as `singleTop`, any incoming Intent at any given will be handled by the currently existing instance, in contrast to creating a new instance of that activity (like a "normal" activity would).

Suppose your app flows like this (with `B` labeled as a `singleTop` activity):

A -> B

1. The user opens activity `B` from activity `A`.
2. While `B` is being opened, another part of your activity
   (be it `BroadcastReceiver`, `Service`, whatever) sends a new `Intent` to `B`
   to do stuff.
3. `B` receives this new Intent and handle it in its `onNewIntent()`
   method.

At this point, when your user taps that back button, `B` will go back to `A`, as opposed to return to the state before step 2.

That is what your "note" basically trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

Consider an activity at the top of the stack. Since it's in the singleTop mode, it receives an intent via `onNewIntent()` method.

Now, suppose that the `onNewIntent()` method loads a new image in an `ImageView` in the activity. Now, when you press back, the `ImageView` wont go back to having the previous image. *i.e.* It won't return to the previous state.

If the stack at this point was A-B-C-D, with D receiving the `onNewIntent()` call. The image view in D gets updated. Now, pressing back, will take the user to C.

In the standard launch mode, the stack becomes A-B-C-D(1)-*(receive new intent)*-D(2), and in this case, when you press back from D(2) you're taken back to D(1).